# NullPointerException if I restart tomcat

Tags: java, session, jsf-2, logout

I have created web application using JSF 2.0. I have created one Session bean where I am keeping id of the employee who is logged in.

The problem is when I do some changes in coding and restart tomcat online, I get Null Pointer exception (IF I have not logged out of the system. If I logged out of system, I don't get null pointer exception). To overcome this, I have to clear the history of the browser and the problem get solved.

Below are the steps I follow for project to make online.

1. Do changes in code
2. Copy war files to my VPS
3. shutdown tomcat
4. remove ROOT folder
5. change the war file name to ROOT.war
6. start the tomcat again

Please suggest me what to do....

Comment: And what is your question? What to do? Do not store logged user in session, save credentials (session id) in cookies and get User every time from database.

Comment: Question here and answer also here.then what u need?

Comment: @ILLA : I didn't answer here....

Comment: Also Remove the work/Catalina/<host>/... files.  Also ensure to post the NullPointerException stack trace in the question.  What code is it and where is it throwing exception ?

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do ?

what is happening is when you do not close your browser , the user is still in session , cookies, session id etc exists.

now when you restart the server without closing IE /deleting history (as you say) then the browser will look for the session id on server which will not be there (as you have restarted it) so it throws a nullPointerException.

You dont need to do anything, this is expected behaviour. 
Logout before you restart or close the browser after you restart the server(note a new tab wont work as session is maintained within tabs. ) and your program will work normally and you wont get any nullpointers

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However what if I forget to logout and restart the server? How can I overcome the null pointer exception? I have to get solution as I can't go and tell all employee to logout...

Comment: if you forget to logout and restart the server. in this case, if you close the existing browser window and open a new one. it would work as expected. a session inside a browser is maintained untill u logout. or you close the browser.

Also , if you really want to do something like that. you can write code to clear cookies , session IDs etc inside a destructor 

also are you expecting the employee to have access to server and restart it ?